Proper toggle buttons in a Compose Material 3 toolbar?
I'm creating a rich text editor toolbar with toggle buttons (e.g., Bold, Italic, List, etc.) using Jetpack Compose and Material Design 3. The default IconToggleButton has a subtle selected state (just tints the icon), which isn't very visible. How can I make the selected state stand out more while keeping the design consistent with Material 3?

You can use the IconToggleButton composable and customize the checkedContainerColor to improve the contrast for the selected state. Here's how you can do it:
val icon = Icons.Outlined.FormatAlignCenter
IconToggleButton(
    checked = isSelected,
    onCheckedChange = { onClick() },
    modifier = modifier,
    colors = IconButtonDefaults.iconToggleButtonColors(
        checkedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
    ),
) {
    Icon(
        icon,
        contentDescription = icon.name,
    )
}

By setting checkedContainerColor to MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer, the button's background changes when selected, making the state more prominent and visually clear.

